# Is there any significance to red or green rays in "Mars Attacks!"?

Tags: mars-attacks

In the movie *Mars Attacks!*, the Martian soldiers shoot either a red ray or a green ray from their guns.

[image: A picture from the movie "Mars Attacks!", depicting three armed Martians shooting their rays at humans. One is shooting a green ray, while the other is shooting a red one.]

These seem to leave skeletons of the same color as the ray that hit the humans.

[image: A picture from the movie "Mars Attacks!" depicting a red skeleton still burning, from a human victim that got him with a Martian gun that shoots red rays.]

[image: Another picture from the movie "Mars Attacks!", depicting this time a green skeleton, from a human victim that got hit with a Martian gun that shoots green rays.]

<sup>(All images taken from [here](https://youtu.be/rXUOHb9K9Mo))</sup>

But the rifles shooting either color ray both seem to have the same red/blue coloration.

Is there any explanation in or out of universe that explains the different ray colors?

Comment: Kill counting :D . Martians are doing this for fun, red team vs green team. Kidding, I have no idea why that is.

Comment: @jo1storm Given how the Martians act ("We are your friends!") it wouldn't surprise me that it is a kill count!  But alas I see no red/green kill count comparison anywhere.

Comment: @jo1storm It's so much in the vein of the movie that I would make that an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is, actually, though only out of universe.

> In the first drafts of the script and in the novelization, the
> Martians' ray-guns had a variety of lethal, graphic effects. Victims
> were bisected, body parts were cut off, huge holes were blown through
> them. Other victims were melted, shredded, or turned into flame. To
> avoid an "R" rating from the MPAA, the producers toned down the
> effects of the Martian rays, and victims were reduced to skeletons.

> When people had their flesh vaporized from their bones, the remaining
> skeletons were either red or green. Tim Burton explained this had been
> done because the movie had been scheduled for a Christmas release.
> Also, the red and green skeletons were first seen in Beetlejuice
> (1988). When Barbara and Adam were in Juno's office, you can see them
> with other ghouls looking at the screen.

Source: [IMDB *Mars Attacks!* Trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116996/trivia)

Comment: That's awesome! So festive...